# Disable MVC cache after redirect?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect

I have a page (prc.aspx) that process a request and then redirect the user to another page which is not in my application domain (gtw.aspx). notice that prc.aspx is an MVC page and has a controller with an Index action which accepts both of GET and POST verbs.

now when I click on the back button in gtw.aspx it redirects me to the prc.aspx but my breakpoint does not stop the execution routine. but I will redirect to the gtw.aspx page again.

I think this is a cached page an do not trigger the action. how can I stop this caching and handle this user return to the site?

Comment: Do you want the prc.aspx page to stop execution when it is navigated back from gtw.aspx?

Comment: I prefer to detect this event and log that and then make a decision to handle this problem.

Comment: you can handle it in many ways, Store some token in session before navigating to gtw.aspx and on page load of prc.aspx validate the token

Comment: Add some code and so can help you where to append session

Comment: prc page is an MVC page and has no load event also back button do not trigger my index action to validate this session token.